# Azure API Set-body JSON to JSON covert

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

The response i am getting is below Which i need to convert the input JSON Format to other JSON structure and send the response back. I am struck how to get the data from the JSOn and construct the new JSON format

```
{
  "totalSize": 1,
  "done": true,
  "records": [{
    "attributes": {
      "type": "test123",
      "url": "/services/data/testapp"
    },
    "Id": "8373837",
    "Name": "6294",
    "Application": "9932932932",
    "contact": {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "testcon",
        "url": "/services/data/testappsss"
      },
      "Name": "testName",
      "FirstName": "test",
      "LastName": "name",
      "MailingStreet": null,
      "MailingCity": null,
      "unemail": "testname@test,.co",
      "MailingState": null,
      "MailingCountry": null,
      "MailingPostalCode": null,
      "stuId": "328237832"
    },
    "currentusbss": "83277832873278",
    "currentsu": {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "testsub",
        "url": "/services/data/v44.0jsjsj"
      },
      "price": 2,
      "Name": "SUB-20426"
    },
    "bal": 234,
    "startdate": "2020-02-03",
    "enddate": "2020-05-03"
  }]
}
```

I need to convert above JSON format to below JSON format and send it using set-body method in out-bond policies

```
{
  "info": {
    "studentName": "testName",
    "studentFirstName": "test",
    "studentMiddleName": "",
    "studentLastName": "Name",
    "studentEmail": "testname@test,.co",
    "role": "STUDENT",
    "billingCountryCode": "US",
    "systemId": "XX",
    "stuId": "328237832"
  },
  "address": {
    "address1": "1234 Grove St",
    "address2": "",
    "city": "Tempe",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "countryDescription": "UNITED STATES",
    "stateCode": "AZ",
    "stateDescription": "Arizona",
    "postalCode": "45235",
    "foreignState": "Arizona",
    "region": "Domestic",
    "phoneNumber": ""
  },
  "account": {
    "institutionId": "1",
    "paymentPlan": "N",
    "currencyDesc": "United States Dollars",
    "currencyType": "USD",
      "bal": 234,
      "daysLate":"18",
      "opportunityId": "9932932932",
      "studentParameterName": null,
    "studentParameterValue": null
  },
  "studentTerms": [
    {
        "startdate": "2020-02-03",
        "enddate": "2020-05-03",
       "Name": "SUB-20426",
      "description": "XQYember 03, 2020 "
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can use Liquid Template for this case:
https://www.codit.eu/blog/using-liquid-templates-in-azure-api-management/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBody

Or you create a new body in the outbound-section with a new JObject

Comment: @MarkusMeyer, this should really be put as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Liquid Template for this case:

[Using Liquid Templates in Azure API Management](https://www.codit.eu/blog/using-liquid-templates-in-azure-api-management/)

[Using Liquid templates with set body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBody)

Or you create a new body in the outbound-section with a new JObject